# What's the "call" of "LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)" in Android.mk?

Tags: android, shell, build, makefile, android-ndk

Below is the first line of Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
```

What is `call`? A shell command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`call` is the make function for calling declared functions. Make syntax isn't equal to normal shell syntax even if some parts look similar, so `$()` isn't a subshell invocation, but a variable evaluation or an invocation of a make function, where `call` is the function for calling user-defined functions. See e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html for further details on the matter.

The make equivalent of `$()` (or ``` `` ```) is `$(shell ...)`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html for details on that one.